LuaLaTeX omits part of a pgfplots diagram
When I run the same pgfplots code using pdflatex and lualatex, I get a different output. lualatex is omitting part of my plot.
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\begin{axis}[%
        axis equal,
        enlargelimits = true,
        %samples = 45, samples y = 45,
        axis lines = none, ticks = none,
        cyl/.style = {%
                surf,
                black!30!,
                variable = \u,
                variable y = \v,
                z buffer = sort,
                faceted color=black!70!,
                },
        %view/h = 125, view/v = 25
        ]

    \addplot3[%         (-) Z-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = -3:3,
        y domain = 0:360,
        ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {min(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = -3:3,
        y domain = 0:360,
        ] ({min(u,-abs(cos(v)),-abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) Y-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = 0:360,
        y domain = -3:3,
        ] ({cos(u)}, {max(v,abs(cos(u)),abs(sin(u)))}, {sin(u)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = -3:3,
        y domain = 0:360,
        ] ({max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = -3:3,
        y domain = 0:360,
        ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) Y-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain = 0:360,
        y domain = -3:3,
        ] ({cos(u)}, {min(-abs(cos(u)),-abs(sin(u)),v)}, {sin(u)});

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

With pdflatex:

With lualatex


remove compat=1.18 to force backwards compatibility mode. remove axis equal to get rid of the subsequent warning. report regression.

in 1.12 the lua backend was introduced which replaces various code with lua code, and rather obviously there is a bug. You could force the standard pdflatex code  by using lua backend=false on this plot.

Ref. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/492#issue-2521285570
Workaround: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/492#issuecomment-2356151408
Fix: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/1359#issue-2531378966
I've not investigated this in any depth, but it appears to be a regression in pgfplots 1.12. As a workaround, you may be able to use
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

and remove axis equal (possibly) from the axis configuration options.
Tested in article to exclude any possible complications from standalone and with scale=3 removed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=3]
  \begin{axis}[%
      % axis equal,
      enlargelimits = true,
      axis lines = none, ticks = none,
      cyl/.style = {%
        surf,
        black!30!,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        z buffer = sort,
        faceted color=black!70!,
      },
    ]

    \addplot3[%         (-) Z-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = -3:3,
      y domain = 0:360,
    ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {min(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) X-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = -3:3,
      y domain = 0:360,
    ] ({min(u,-abs(cos(v)),-abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) Y-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = 0:360,
      y domain = -3:3,
    ] ({cos(u)}, {max(v,abs(cos(u)),abs(sin(u)))}, {sin(u)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = -3:3,
      y domain = 0:360,
    ] ({max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = -3:3,
      y domain = 0:360,
    ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) Y-SEMIAXIS
      cyl,
      domain = 0:360,
      y domain = -3:3,
    ] ({cos(u)}, {min(-abs(cos(u)),-abs(sin(u)),v)}, {sin(u)});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Interestingly, if you remove compat completely, you get console warnings about wrong output, but the actual output looks fine. This is also where I got the advice to remove axis equal.

I apologize for not saying thanks earlier. You clearly put a lot of effort into finding a solution to this, and it was really cool to be a part of.

@Jasper not required, but always appreciated :-). but this was really only a workaround. the real solution will hopefully end up in some future pgfplots.

It seems that the Lua version of min currently only handles the first two arguments. Thus, until the bug is fixed, a workaround is to reformulate min(x,y,z) to min(x,min(y,z)).
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal,
        enlargelimits=true,
        axis lines=none,
        ticks=none,
        cyl/.style={
            surf,
            black!30!,
            variable=\u,
            variable y=\v,
            z buffer=sort,
            faceted color=black!70!,
        },
    ]

    \addplot3[%         (-) Z-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=-3:3,
        y domain=0:360,
    ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {min(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=-3:3,
        y domain=0:360,
    ] ({min(u,-abs(cos(v)),-abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) Y-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=-3:3,
    ] ({cos(u)}, {max(v,abs(cos(u)),abs(sin(u)))}, {sin(u)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=-3:3,
        y domain=0:360,
    ] ({max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))}, {cos(v)}, {sin(v)});

    \addplot3[%         (+) X-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=-3:3,
        y domain=0:360,
    ] ({cos(v)}, {sin(v)}, {max(u,abs(cos(v)),abs(sin(v)))});

    \addplot3[%         (-) Y-SEMIAXIS
        cyl,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=-3:3,
%    ] ({cos(u)}, {min(-abs(cos(u)),-abs(sin(u)),v)}, {sin(u)});
    ] ({cos(u)}, {min(-abs(cos(u)),min(-abs(sin(u)),v))}, {sin(u)});    % <-- workaround

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/492#issuecomment-2356151408

I guess this works because it forces lua to handle only two values at a time, which the min and max functions can handle.
